# search in array of objects in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-6.4.3

I have created an index test_index with the following mapping:

```
PUT test_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "segments": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "f1": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "f2": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I inserted a document in the index with the following command:

```
POST /test_index/_doc
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "segments": [{
    "f1": "abc",
    "f2": 123
  }, 
  {
    "f1": "def",
    "f2": 124
  }]
}
```

I have an array of values say `arr = ["def", "xyz"]`. I want to match all the documents whose atleast one of the `f1 field in segments field` match with any of the values in the given array `arr`.

You can call it something like array_intersect to easier to understand.

I am trying something like this:

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
"query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "segments",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "f1": [ 
                  "def",
                  "xyz"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting no results as the output. 
`Expected output`: The document should match as "def" is present as value of f1 in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify the full path in your terms query as `segments.f1` instead of `f1` for [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

Modify the query as below:

```
POST test_index/_search
{ 
   "query":{ 
      "nested":{ 
         "path":"segments",
         "query":{ 
            "bool":{ 
               "must":[ 
                  { 
                     "terms": {
                       "segments.f1": ["def","xyz"]    <---- Mention full path here

                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't it the same as IN clause equivalent?